# Equations of motion for correlation functions (Ex 2.2 of yellow book)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, correlation-functions

The yellow book on conformal field theory contains the following exercise 2.2:

> Consider a generic quantum field $\phi$ with the action $S[\phi]$, and the correlation function:
> $$\langle X \rangle = \frac{1}{Z} \int [d\phi] X e^{iS}$$
> where $X$ stands for an expression involving the fields. By performing an infinitesimal change of functional integration variables $\phi \to \phi + \delta \phi$ show:
> $$\left\langle \frac{\delta X}{\delta \phi(x)} \right\rangle = -i \left\langle X \frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi(x)} \right\rangle. $$

My question: Now, if I make a change of variables and call the new variables $\phi'$ I get:
$$\int [d\phi'] X[\phi'] e^{iS[\phi']} = \int [d\phi] X[\phi] e^{iS[\phi]} \rm{.}$$
Now if I expand to first order $S[\phi'] = S[\phi] + \frac{\delta D}{\delta \phi}\delta \phi$ and similarly for $X$ and I assume $[d \phi']=[d \phi]$, I get the claim of the exercise. I wonder though, can I really use $[d \phi']=[d \phi]$? Shouldn't there be a Jacobian factor in general?

Comment: There is Jacobian factor.

Comment: There is a Jacobian factor. Naively, it should be 1 in the case you mention as this is just a shift in the integration variables. This can be ruined by the regularization procedure, in which case you get an anomaly.